# Sqlite Connection from AppFabric Provider

Tags: sqlite, gac, appfabric

We want to use AppFabric cache on our projects with using Sqlite including ReadThruogh-WriteBehind feature. I successfully created Provider and registered to GAC. If i chose mssql service as data provider, everything works successfully. On the other hand, if i chose sqlite, it throws an exception at this line on Provider in GAC .

```
SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(@"path");
```

This exception comes from Provider in GAC, but if i write this line in service, it works. So problem is, if i want to connect sqlite from GAC, it throws an exception:

> The cache provider threw an exception during read.

There is no more explanation in error message, but if try to connect sqlite from service, it connects successfully. Sqlite db file allows everyone to read.

It seems there is an authentication problem or something like that. What can be the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging provider in GAC, issue was about System.Data.SQLite.dll. I had to register that dll into a GAC too, because it tries to find that dll from gac too, for this reason it threw an exception. You need to be sure that, dll should have strong name. To make it has strong name, you need to do following instructions,

```
 1. sn -k keyPair.snk  
 2. ildasm System.Data.SQLite.dll
 3. /out:System.Data.SQLite.il  ren System.Data.SQLite.dll
 4. System.Data.SQLite.dll.orig  ilasm System.Data.SQLite.il /dll /key=
    keyPair.snk
```

If your dll has already strong name(you can check it from dll properties) you dont need to do these steps. you can directly register dll into a GAC by following this code,

```
gacutil -i System.Data.SQLite.dll
```

I hope it will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

From http://msdn.developer-works.com/article/12056989/.ErrorCode%26lt%3BERRCA0025%26gt%3B%3ASubStatus%26lt%3BES0001%26gt%3B

> The error code that you are getting translates to DataCacheErrorCode.ReadThroughProviderFailure so this is an error which is happening on the service side and not the client side so
>   client configuration will not help.
>
> In this case you should first
>   check if you have created a Read-Through provider and installed it on
>   the Caching server.
>
> You will get this error if you have created a
>   CUSTOM Read-Through provider (something new in AppFabric 1.1) and an
>   exception is happening in the READ method of that provider. More
>   details about creating the provider at
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361698(v=azure.10).aspx
>
> If this is a reproducible error, then you should be able to easily Debug
>   the DistributedCacheService.exe process on the Cache server and put a
>   breakpoint on the PUT method and step through it to see if you can
>   find the exception.
>
> The section Testing and debugging the provider out
>   this in detail.

Comment: thanks stuartd for the answer but as its written "In this case you should first check if you have created a Read-Through provider" i checked sqlite and i know that problem is on that line. when i try to open sqliteconnection in GAC, it throws an exception, while it works when i try  to open in wcf web service. Do you have an idea, what can be the reason of cant connect to sqlite in GAC?

Comment: As the [referenced article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361698(v=azure.10).aspx) says, setup a single-node cache cluster on the development machine and debug it, that should shed some light on why it isn't working

Comment: yes as you said, after debugging provider in GAC, issue comes from SQLite.dll. I think i need to register System.Data.SQLite.dll into a GAC. I will share it when everything works fine.